# 504 - Gateway Timeout when using Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I just started using Azure and createad an Azure CDN with https and querystrings enabled.
When accessing images through http theres no issues both when accessing the same image through https i get "504 - Gateway Timeout".

Try the links below. The first one through normal http works but the second one through https doesn't:

http://az620855.vo.msecnd.net/profiles/user-cc667cfc-fc9a-4343-9a2f-90f5d3539c08/profile-c5c108a0-1a7c-46a3-b00a-5607f6458973.jpg?size=WWW-ProfilePictureSmall

https://az620855.vo.msecnd.net/profiles/user-cc667cfc-fc9a-4343-9a2f-90f5d3539c08/profile-c5c108a0-1a7c-46a3-b00a-5607f6458973.jpg?size=WWW-ProfilePictureSmall

Any ideas why?

Comment: I get 404 on HTTPS link and 503 Gateway Timeout on the HTTP. Are you sure you have correctly configured the CDN and there is a content to serve?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Found this article http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/ and uploaded certificate to my Cloud Service

Worked right away.

Comment: Just curious - do you need an SSL cert even if you're not serving content over https ? I got intermittent 504's using the CDN and the entire site was http only.